# Move relative layout from AlignParentBottom to AlignParentTop

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm doing this in Xamarin, so there will be slight deviations in the casing and names of methods.

I have a RelativeLayout that has ads and is placed at the bottom.  Unfortunately, the ads block part of the playable map, so I'm attempting to move it to the top when the player moves near the bottom.  I initialize the banner with the following code:

```
    _banner = new RelativeLayout(this);
    _lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
    _lp.AddRule(LayoutRules.AlignParentBottom);
    _lp.AddRule(LayoutRules.AlignParentLeft);
    AddContentView(_banner, _lp);
```

I'm now attempting to move it to the top, but am failing.  I've tried removing and re-adding it, but that does nothing.

```
    var lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
    ((FrameLayout)(_banner.Parent)).RemoveView(_banner);
    lp.AddRule(LayoutRules.AlignParentTop);
    lp.AddRule(LayoutRules.AlignParentLeft);
    AddContentView(_banner, lp);
```

I've also tried setting the LayoutParameters, but that throws an exception.  What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

-Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code I gather you are nesting a RelativeLayout (contains the ad) inside a FrameLayout. Your RelativeLayout only matches your parent in width, not height.
As such the RelativeLayout doesn't have the same size as your FrameLayout.

Your ad is thus touching both top and bottom of the RelativeLayout. And that RelativeLayout is always aligned to the top of the FrameLayout.

To solve this you have three options:

- Make the RelativeLayout match the entire height of the FrameLayout and position your ad within that RelativeLayout.
- Change the FrameLayout into a RelativeLayout, that way your alignParentBottom parameter will start working.
- Use a 'layout_gravity' parameter on the RelativeLayout to tell the FrameLayout you want this View sent to the bottom.

Effectively your code is doing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

But for stuff to work you need to use android:layout_gravity which is a FrameLayout.LayoutParameter.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

Just paste the two pieces in a layout.xml and use the Android Designer to view the difference.

Comment: I agree that my ad is touching both the top and bottom of relative layout.

I initially set the relative layout to AlignParentBottom.  Doesn't this mean that it's always at the bottom?  My second code block removes it and sets it to the top.  Shouldn't that reset it and place it at the top?

I'm not explicitly setting a RelativeLayout inside a FrameLayout.  I'm using MonoGame.  I think the root is a FrameLayout.

Comment: AlignParentTop is a RelativeLayout.LayoutParameter.

FrameLayouts align their children using FrameLayout.LayoutParameters.

I've updated my answer to reflect the difference.

Comment: So does alignParentBottom refer to items inside the RelativeLayout?  Or the positioning of the RelativeLayout itself relative to its parent?

Comment: Neither.

alignParentBottom is used by items inside of a RelativeLayout to refer to the RelativeLayout.

Views inside a RelativeLayout use RelativeLayout.LayoutParams to indicate to their parent where they want to be.

Views inside a FrameLayout use FrameLayout.LayoutParams to indicate to their parent where they want to be.

Comment: Thank you, I switched to layout gravity, and it worked!